# Remain on page after post

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc

This is a really stupid question, but I'm not sure how to do the following:
I have a web app (ASP .Net Core 1.1 MVC) which, when the user clicks a delete button, calls a delete action on a Web API.
        // GET: Property/Delete/5
        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

```
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.DeleteAsync(url);
        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");
            return Ok();
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
```

Basically, the user is on the Index page, then he clicks "Delete" next to a record, and I want it to delete the record, but remain on the Index page (but it should refresh the Index page to show the record is gone). Obviously what I'm doing above is wrong, but I'm not sure hwo to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public async Task Delete(int id) {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.DeleteAsync(url);
                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Redirect(Request.Referrer.ToString());
                }
                return View("Error");
            }
```